# JS .splice() on object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why do i always get "... .splice() is not a function" when using it on arrays with objects??

Does indeed work with numbers, but I need it with objects.

https://jsfiddle.net/a1nq1p73/1/

```
arrayWithObjects.splice(0,1); // "TypeError: ... not a function"
```

I am trying to rearrange sections (`position:absolute`) by their `left` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` does not return an array, the method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements. You would need to convert it to an array.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var nowItIsAnArray = [].slice.call( divs);
```